# React SSR - handle window.height/width

Tags: meteor, reactjs, server-side

I am using React with SSR FlowRouter.

Because of this lines:

```
var height = (Meteor.isClient ? window.innerHeight : 0);
<div style={{top: height+'px' }}>
```

I get such a warning:

`Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server.`

I know thats because of difference between client and server code (I don't have access to window on my server).

Is there any way to avoid this warning?

Comment: Thanks for posting, did you figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

The warning you are facing is because of a checksum error between the initially rendered html on the server and the client. As you correctly pointed out, this is because, you do not have the `window` object on the server and hence, cannot calculate `window.innerHeight`. This is causing the rendered html to differ in the `style` attribute of the `div` and causing the warning.

A possible workaround would be to move the `height` variable to the `state` of the component and set it to an initial state of 0. Then perform the check

```
this.setState({height: (Meteor.isClient ? window.innerHeight : 0)});
```

in `componentWillMount` and set the correct height here. This way the initial render of both client and server would be the same. But, since `componentDidMount` is only called on the client, it will re-render the component with the correct `height` from the `window` when the `state` is changed.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate)

> If you intentionally need to render something different on the server and the client, you can do a two-pass rendering. Components that render something different on the client can read a state variable like `this.state.isClient`, which you can set to `true` in `componentDidMount()`. This way the initial render pass will render the same content as the server, avoiding mismatches, but an additional pass will happen synchronously right after hydration. Note that this approach will make your components slower because they have to render twice, so use it with caution.